# Reduced word is uniquely written

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, formal-languages, combinatorial-group-theory

Given a family of groups $\{G_i:i\in I\}$ we may assume that $G_i$ are pairwise disjoint. Let $X=\bigcup^{}_{i\in I}G_i$ and let $\{1\}$ be one element disjoint from $X.$ A word on on $X$ is any sequence $(a_1, a_2, ...)$ such that $a_i ∈ X \cup \{1\}$ and for some $n ∈ N, a_i = 1$ for all $i ≥ n.$
A word $(a_1, a_2,...)$ is *reduced* if:

$(a)$ no $a_i ∈ X$ is the identity element in its group $G_i;$

$(b)$ for all $i ≥ 1, a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$ are not in the same group $G_i;$

$(c)$ $a_k = 1$ implies $a_i = 1$ for all $i ≥ k.$

In particular $1=(1,1,...,1)$ is reduced. Show that every reduced word can be written uniquely as $a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot ... \cdot a_n=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n,1,1,...),$where $a_i \in X.$

I dont even know if I understand definition, but here is my attempt:

Assume some word can't be written uniquely, so:

$a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot ... \cdot a_n$=$b_1\cdot b_2 \cdot ... \cdot b_n$

$b_1^{-1}\cdot a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot ... \cdot a_n = e_1 \cdot b_2 \cdot ... \cdot b_n$.

$e_1$ is indentity element in $G_1$. Contradiction with $(a)$ point.

Comment: May you can tell us where you found this problem/definition?

Comment: @Dominik This is problem given by my professor for homework. Why you asking?

Comment: Firstly, your attempt does not work, because "multiplication" has not been defined on this set. This problem looks to be setting up a "normal form" for free products of groups. It also seems to be extremely simple, and not really worthy of a proof, unless I am missing something. This is because there is no concept of "equality" in the sequences $a_1\cdot a_2\cdots\ldots \cdot a_n$, apart from the one inherited via their definition. That is, by their definition, two of these sequences are equal if and only if their corresponding reduced words are equal.

Comment: (In summary, the question is either missing a definition of "equality" for the sequences $a_1\cdot a_2\cdots\ldots \cdot a_n$, or is elementary.)